# reload process.env variables without reboot

Tags: node.js, environment-variables

Can we reload environment variables (`process.env`) with the updated values without restarting the nodejs app or server ?

In other words, I have created a new environment variable (`NEW_VARIABLE`) and have set a value in my Windows 7 machine. Now I have written a function to read the environment variable as below in my NodeJS application.

```
setInterval(() => {
    console.log(process.env.NEW_VARIABLE);
}, 5000);
```

Comment: try using module [dotenv](https://www.npmjs.com/package/dotenv)

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can, see code below where we run 2 loops, one to read and another to increment the variable.

```
setInterval(() => {
    process.env.NEW_VARIABLE++;
},
1000);

setInterval(() => {
    console.log(process.env.NEW_VARIABLE);
},
1000);
```

When you update the variable, the next read will be updated.

Unless you are using some packages that has caching behaviour, I have seen that in a few packages.

Comment: Hi Neo, Thanks for quick response. I created the new environment variable in windows from the commandline SET NEW_VARIABLE=test and then run the app with the command "node app". While the app is running, I changed the value of the environment variable SET NEW_VARIABLE=test123. But the function above is still displaying the old value "test" instead of "test123".

Answer (score 0):

You should try something like this

```
process.env.NEW_VARIABLE = process.env.mode + 1;
```

or

```
process.env.NEW_VARIABLE = process.env.NEW_VARIABLE++;
```

This is going to modify it albeit temporary.